# Does Atom support CSS snippets

Tags: atom-editor

I was able to add JavaScript snippets in the Atom editor, but I couldn't add CSS snippets. Is there a way to add CSS snippets in Atom?

```
#js this works fine
".source.js":  
  "getElementById":  
    "prefix": "geid"  
    "body": "documnet.getElementById($1)"  

#css this does not work
".source.css":
  "blue background":
    "prefix": "bgblue"
    "body": " background-color: blue "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it exactly as you posted, and it worked for me.

Make sure your Atom is fully updated, and make sure the document you're trying to use the snippet in is using the appropriate language/grammar.

Comment: Yep, I was very behind with updates, just updated atom worked like a charm, Thank ya!